# How to add Backbone Model global function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reset, backbone-model

I need to add a function for all my models, but I can´t do how to recognize the model as "this" scope variable. My function will do my model can be reseted to the defaults and by some data-object as parameter:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.reset = function( data ){

        this.set(this.defaults);

        $.each( data, function( key, value ){

              this.set( key, value );
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems legit. the value of `this` is defined at runtime and depends on how you call your method. if you will use `modelInstance.reset()` the value of `this` will be `modelInstance`.

However, mutating the prototype of a 3rd party is considered a bad practice that should be avoided. A better practice is to create an abstract model and have all of your model implement it.

It will look something like:

```js
var AbstracrtModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  reset: function (data, options) {
    this.clear(options);
    this.set(_.defaults({}, data || {}, this.defaults || {}), options);
  }
});
```

*The api of [`model.set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) permits passing a data hash, so you don't really need the inner loop.*

Answer (score 2):

Your "this" context inside the $.each is the iterator. You could get a

```
var self = this;
$.each( data, function( key, value ){
    self.set( key, value );
});
```

And the use self inside the each function, or bind the context to the function.

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ){
    this.set( key, value );
}.bind(this));
```